# How to "catch" all changed objects and call api for every of them?

Tags: angular

```
  <div class="ui-g" *ngFor="let product of products;let i=index" (change)="sum(i)" (click)="selectItemForDelete(product)">
    <input  class="ui-g-6" type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.productName" disabled>
     <div class="ui-g-6 center">
          <input class="ui-g-2" [(ngModel)]="product.quantity">
          <input class="ui-g-4 right"  [ngModel]="product.itemamount | toNumber | number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="product.itemamount = $event">
          <input class="ui-g-2 right"  [ngModel]="product.discountamount | toNumber | number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="product.discountamount = $event">
          <input class="ui-g-4 right" [ngModel]="product.unitprice | toNumber | number:'1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="product.unitprice = $event">
     </div>
```

I have api that recives only one item. So what i want is to "catch" all changed objects and call api for every of them. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: I am not sure what infrastructure you are using. Maybe change the api to receive an array of  ' product ' instead of one single product ?

Comment: yea but still i dont know how to send all objects that i changed ?

Comment: Initiate a http post request to the api server using the angular http module which receives the request. What technology are you using in the backend ?

Comment: i dont have problem with backed, i dont know how to send objects that they are changed from frontend

Comment: Might be helpful if you also post your existing typescript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind having several http calls, what you can do is implement OnChanges :

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
    ngOnChanges() {
        // Each time your model changes, this function is called
        // Make your http calls here. 
        // You can use Observable.debounceTime() to delay calls 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's completely incorrect. ngOnChanges is only called when a different **input** is passed by the parent component.

Comment: I very much doubt it.

Comment: Well I'm not the one marking the answers as resolved !

Comment: But you could admit your answer is completely wrong anyway. Just see by yourself: http://plnkr.co/edit/ziJ2BfaQ2JcpTT30XF8t?p=preview

Comment: I can't admit that because I'm using it in my project. But I do agree that ngOnChanges doesn't trigger for every model change. Again, we don't have all of his code, and he probably adapted it to make it work, while all I did was giving him an hint. So calm down dude !